# How to execute a method with parameters as different threads independently in C#?

Tags: c#

i have method called kcopy() which has parameters of string src and string desti for copying folder and contents. I also have two arrays namely sourcearray[] and destiarray[] which has some list of paths, i have to  copy contents selected in the sourcearray to list of destination paths in which i call the method Kcopy();. how can i execute the kcopy method parallel'y  for the different destination paths at the same time using C# code

Comment: can you share some code ?

Comment: Have you looked at [`Parallel.For`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for(v=vs.110).aspx)?